# Finding location in code for numpy RuntimeWarning

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting warnings like these when running numpy on reasonably large pipeline.

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater

How do I find where they are occurring in the code besides writing dozens of print statements?

Python 2.7 and numpy 1.8.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way is to convert the warnings to errors:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('error', RuntimeWarning)
```

Then the traceback will tell you where the error occurred.

*Thanks to @Graham501617 for the following tip:*

This can be done without code changes using the python cli:

```
python -Werror my_script.py
```

See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) for more information.

Comment: This can be done without code changes using the python cli: `python -Werror my_script.py`. https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W