# Python numpy Runtime warning using np.where np.errstate and warnings 'error'

Tags: python, numpy, division

I keep getting the runtime warning about division.
In the code below, I used the answer of [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64747346/numpy-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-true-divide-on-np-where) from this forum and even imported warnings error from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546563/finding-location-in-code-for-numpy-runtimewarning).

```
def alpha_n(V):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        alph = np.where(V!= -55, 0.01*(V+55)/(1-np.exp(-0.1*(V+55))), 0.1)
    return alph
```

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

How could I define the function properly to avoid warnings?

Comment: What version of python do you use? Also, could you provide an example of data you send through your function `alpha_n`

Comment: Using `np.where` to avoid bad values is not a good idea.  They are still evaluated.  An alternative is use `np.divide` ufunc with its own `where` (and `out`) parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [26]: def alpha_n(V):
    ...:     with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
    ...:         alph = np.where(V!= -55, 0.01*(V+55)/(1-np.exp(-0.1*(V+55))), 0
    ...: .1)
    ...:     return alph
    ...: 
In [27]: alpha_n(np.array([1,2,3,-55]))
Out[27]: array([0.56207849, 0.5719136 , 0.58176131, 0.1       ])
```

Divide by 0 is different from invalid value:

```
In [28]: 1/(1-np.exp(-0.1*(np.array([-55])+55)))
<ipython-input-28-ed83c58d75bb>:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  1/(1-np.exp(-0.1*(np.array([-55])+55)))
Out[28]: array([inf])
In [29]: 0/(1-np.exp(-0.1*(np.array([-55])+55)))
<ipython-input-29-0d642b423038>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  0/(1-np.exp(-0.1*(np.array([-55])+55)))
Out[29]: array([nan])
```